# I would like know if have possibility of add a new metric in eclipse metrics plugin

Tags: eclipse, metrics, code-metrics

I would like know if have possibility of add a new metric in eclipse metrics plugin.
for example: don't have the metric TCC - Tight Class Cohesion, I would like add in list of preference.

Answer (score 0):

I've already added a number of cohesion metrics, including TCC, but I don't think that they've been incorporated in an official release.  You might try downloading my version of the metrics plug-in from http://code.google.com/p/ext-c/downloads/detail?name=net.sourceforge.metrics_2.0.0.201105311759.jar&can=2&q=.

You can find the [TCC source](http://sourceforge.net/p/metrics2/code/153/tree//dev/net.sourceforge.metrics/src/net/sourceforge/metrics/calculators/CohesionTCC.java) on sourceforge in the Metrics2 project.

Good luck!